# Search and paginate in PHP string error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my problem is when I try to display results from `SELECT * from table WHERE x Like y` pagination is working but no data displayed, and receive this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in E:\server\htdocs\pag.php on line 118 [this is 118: while($linie = mysql_fetch_array("$result"))] here is my code:

```
<?php include('/SQL.php'); ?>

<?php   $tbl_name="modele";     //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;
 $cautare = $_GET['c']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE (`marca` LIKE '%".$cautare."%') OR (`model` LIKE '%".$cautare."%')";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "paginare.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 3;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page=isset($_GET['pagina'])?(int)$_GET['pagina']:0;
$page=mysql_real_escape_string($page);
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
        WHERE (`marca` LIKE '%".$cautare."%') OR (`model` LIKE '%".$cautare."%') 
        LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());echo $result;



/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$prev\">« Inapoi</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« Inapoi</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$next\">Inainte »</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Inainte »</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($linie = mysql_fetch_array("$result"))
    {

    echo '<div id="content"><div id="content">
         <div class="post">
        <h3><a href=/articol.php?id='.$linie["id"].'>'.$linie["marca"].' '.$linie["model"].'</a></h3>
        <span class="info"><img style="float: left;" src="/foto.php?src=panou/'.$linie['img1'].'&h=180&w=120"></img><br />
        <h4> CPU: Nr de nuclee: '.$linie["performanta_cpu_core"].' x '.$linie["performanta_cpu"].' Mhz<br /><br /><br />
         RAM: '.$linie["performanta_rami"].'MB<br /><br /><br />
         BATERIE: '.$linie["baterie_mAh"].' mAh<br /><br /><br />
         FOTO: '.$linie["camera_fata"].' MP</h4><br /><br /><br />
        '.$linie["despre"].'</span>
        <span class="user">de <a href="http://plus.google.com/u/0/111829192724498190405" title="author" rel="author">'.$linie["utilizator"].'</a></span>
        <span class="comment">27 Comentarii</span>
    </div></div>
    <br /><br />';

    }
?>  <?=$pagination?>
```

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Read up on sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes
`while($linie = mysql_fetch_array($result))`
and make sure the query had no errors with
`echo mysql_error();`

Comment: No error printed, page shows just pagination, an pagination is working property like before... ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sql` query on line #24 is most likely failing as you are missing the `,` in your `limit`, so when you get to `while($linie = mysql_fetch_array("$result"))` `$result` is a string, not a resource that can be used in `mysql_fetch_array()` -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE (`marca` LIKE '%".$c."%') OR (`model` LIKE '%".$c."%') LIMIT $start $limit";
                                                                                                         ^
```

Change to -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE (`marca` LIKE '%".$c."%') OR (`model` LIKE '%".$c."%') LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Be aware that you are open to sql injection as you are using unsanitized data in your queries - `$c = $_GET['c'];`. You should change from `mysql_*` functions to either `mysqli_` or `PDO` and utilized prepared statements.

Comment: same problem: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in E:\server\htdocs\pag.php on line 122 
But pagination work good...

Comment: Change line #25 to `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());echo $result;` and post either the `mysql_error()` or the results of the `$result` echo.

Comment: This is the error when i put '$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());echo $result;' in result line:Resource id #17 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in E:\server\htdocs\pag.php on line 122

Comment: Have you verified that your connection `mysql_connect()` and db selection `mysql_select_db()` are working? I assume this is in `/SQL.php`.

Comment: Yes is working, because pagination is working an if i follow localhost/pag.php?c=nokia pagination is working and appears button 1 and 2 wih results of nokia but data is not displayed

Comment: Are you using `$sql` or `$result` as vars in `/SQL.php`? ie. `$sql=mysql_connect($host, $user,$password); $result=mysql_select_db($db,$sql)`? Or anywhere else in your file?

Comment: thi is my SQL.php: `<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
$user = 'test';
$password = 'test1';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Conectare SQL nereusita: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>`

Comment: That is your problem. You are connecting using `new PDO()` but using `mysql_query()`. Try changing to something like `$sql = "..."; $stmt = $dbh->query($sql); $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and then `foreach($row as $linie){...}`